# How does using chain rule in backprogation algorithm works?

Tags: calculus, analysis, neural-networks

Let's have a simple error function $E(z) =\frac{1}{2} \times (a - y(z))^2$

How come $\frac{\partial E}{\partial z} = \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dz} \frac{\partial E}{\partial y}$ ?

In other words does it not mean that  $\frac{\partial E}{\partial z} =  \frac{\partial E}{\partial y(z)}$? If so, why?

Since using chain rule $\frac{\partial E}{\partial y(z)} =  \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dz} \frac{\partial E}{\partial y}$? But does not seem to make sense since that would mean that  $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dz} = 1$

This formulas are coming from backpropagation algorithm for neural network.

y is  sigmoid function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chain rule is given by theory, you can accept it as it is. For further reading on the chain rule, you can start from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

Coming back to your question, you say that:
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = 1 .$$

I guess you mean "for all $z$". Then, this is only true if $y(z) = z + b$, for some $b$.
Hence, only when $y(z) = z + b$, you can conclude, by applying the chain rule, that:

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial z} =  \frac{\partial E}{\partial y}.$$

This is no true in general. For example, suppose that:

$$y = \cos(z).$$

Then:

$$E(z) = \frac{1}{2} (a - y(z))^2 = \frac{1}{2} (a - \cos(z))^2.$$

The derivative with respect to $z$ is:

$$\frac{\partial E(z)}{\partial z} = 2\frac{1}{2}(-\sin(z))(a-\cos(z)) = - \sin(z)(a-\cos(z)).$$

Let's try to work with the chain rule. We know that:

$$\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = -\sin(z)\\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial E}{\partial y} = 2\frac{1}{2}(a-y(z)) = a-\cos(z)
\end{cases}
$$

Finally:

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \frac{\partial E}{\partial y} = -\sin(z)(a-\cos(z)).$$

So, you come up to the same result.

---

In the context of neural networks, you may want to set $y(z)$ equal to the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) as a function which describes the activation of a neuron.
This function has a very nice property. Indeed:

$$\frac{\partial y(z)}{\partial z} = y(z)(1-y(z)).$$

Therefore, you don't need to evaluate $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$, since you have it freely knowing only $y(z)$. In this case, you get that:

$$\frac{\partial E(z)}{\partial z} = y(z)(1-y(z))2\frac{1}{2}(a-y(z)) = y(z)(1-y(z))(a-y(z)).$$

In particular, you know the value of $y(z)$ since it corresponds to the activation of a neuron. $a-y(z)$ is the error that you want to backpropagate. Using the sigmoid function, you can avoid to find the derivative of $y(z)$ explicitly, thus obtaining a fast algorithm. Instead, if you need to evaluate explicitly the derivative each time, the algorithm can be slower.

Comment: I thought derivate of $E(y(z))$ is $\frac{\partial E}{\partial y(z)}$, but it is $\frac{\partial E}{\partial z}$. Now the chain rule make sense to me. Thank you for detailed explanation.